# How do I provide authenticated access to my AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I started a bare Expo app with `expo init` called `MyVideoApp`. Then I created an AWS account and in the terminal ran:

- `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`
- `amplify configure`

This signed me into the console, I went through the default steps and created an account in `region:eu-west-2`, `username:amplify-user`, pasted in the `accessKeyId` & `secretAccessKey`, `profile name:amplify-user-profile`.

- `cd ~/Documents/MyVideoApp/` & `amplify init`

```
? Enter a name for the project MyVideoApp
? Enter a name for the environment dev
? Choose your default editor: IntelliJ IDEA
? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
Please tell us about your project
? What javascript framework are you using react-native
? Source Directory Path:  /
? Distribution Directory Path: /
? Build Command:  npm run-script build
? Start Command: npm run-script start
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Do you want to use an AWS profile? Yes
? Please choose the profile you want to use amplify-user-profile
Adding backend environment dev to AWS Amplify Console app: d37chh30hholq6
```

- `amplify push`

At this point I had an `amplify` folder in my project directory and an S3 bucket called `amplify-myvideoapp-dev-50540-deployment`. I uploaded an image into the bucket `icon_1.png`. And tried to download it from the app via a button click.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';

import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

async function getImage() {
  try {
    let data = await Storage.get('icon_1.jpg')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
      <Button title={"Click to Download!"} onPress={getImage}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Output:

```
No credentials

[WARN] 18:54.93 AWSS3Provider - ensure credentials error, No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access
...
```

So I setup (but maybe not correctly?) a user pool (`my_first_pool`) and an identity pool (`myvidapp`). This didn't help. Furthermore when I go into my bucket and click Permissions -> Bucket Policy, it's just empty ... not sure if that's okay if only owner is trying to access the bucket & it's contents.

I don't know what's wrong and what else to try. I essentially just want to authenticate my backend so anyone who `git clone`s this code would just be able to run it and access the bucket.

**Edit**: `aws-exports.js`

```
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-2"
};
export default awsmobile;
```

Comment: Do you need to restrict access to the S3 files at all, or can they be public (i.e. anyone in the world can download them)?

Comment: Ideally I'd only want people who use the app to be able to access it, so I'd hard code the access keys. But if it's easier I could make it public, I just don't want to have some sort of timed access - I just want people to be able to access anytime if they have some keys.

Comment: I guess I could have it public and only allow downloads.

Comment: Hard-coding in access keys is not recommended for security reasons. If the file itself can be made publicly accessible, that is the simplest way to grant access to it. See instructions below.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've indicated that you're okay with all of the files in the S3 bucket being publicly accessible, I would suggest the following:

1. Select the bucket from in the AWS console (console.aws.amazon.com)
2. Under "Permissions" select "Block Public Access" and edit the settings by *un*-checking all of the options under and including "Block all public access", then save and confirm.
3. Go to the bucket policy, and paste in the following (Note: replace "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE" with "amplify-myvideoapp-dev-50540-deployment" first):

> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "PublicRead",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": "*",
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:GetObject",
>                 "s3:GetObjectVersion"
>             ],
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE]/*"
>             ]
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Comment: I've done this and everything is still the same. Is there any variables I need to set in my code? Or do I need to modify ACL?

Comment: Hmmm... You should know when the bucket is publicly accessible, because accessing http://amplify-myvideoapp-dev-50540-deployment.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_1.png in Incognito mode will display the image. I would carefully review the steps above and ensure that you followed them correctly.

Comment: Ya the ObjectURL is accessible so it's public. And yes the bucket name is correct. I also checked `team-provider-info.json` file in project and  `{"dev":{"awscloudformation":{"DeploymnetBucketName":"amplify-awsappvid-dev-50540-deployment"}}}`

Comment: When I visit http://amplify-awsappvid-dev-50540-deployment.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_1.png in incognito mode, I get <Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>amplify-myvideoapp-dev-50540-deployment</BucketName>
<RequestId>3274383AAA4C432C</RequestId>
<HostId>knp6oxkAsCGPsota8Ci3n4d0ijhBJ9UPVwzg1lZn8wsNScfY2UpgvIHXF9k6P17a78GSwyfdm9w=</HostId>
</Error>, so why don't you provide me with the exact url that you say is working for viewing the image in your browser in Incognito mode.